# Can't Promisify node-ftp Function

Tags: node.js, async-await, ftp, node-promisify

I am using the [node-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp) library and I would like to promisify certain methods (`list()` and `get()`).

I am aware that there are promise-based wrappers, but I need to return the readable stream (and not write to a local file) and node-ftp allows this.

the `get()` method appears to follow the right pattern for promisification, but I cannot get it to work:

***list([< string >path, ][< boolean >useCompression, ]< function >callback)***

The non-promisified code works as expected

```
// THIS WORKS

var Client = require('ftp');

var c = new Client();

c.on('ready', function () {
  c.list('/mypath', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
});
c.connect()
```

.. the promisified code does not:

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK

var Client = require('ftp');
var { promisify } = require('util');

var c = new Client();

var ftp_list = promisify(c.list)

c.on('ready', function () {

  ftp_list('/mypath')
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })      
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error', err);
      });    

});
c.connect()
```

returns error: `TypeError: this._pasv is not a function`

The presence of `this.` in the error makes me think this is an arrow function issue, but using a normal function did not work either.

Can this node-ftp function (and likewise `c.get()`) be promisified this way?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass `c.list` to `promisify`, you want it to *keep* the calling context of `c` (so that the `this` used by the implementation of `.list` has the `_pasv` property), so use `.bind`:

```
var ftp_list = promisify(c.list.bind(c))
```